# Getting this error (Generic detail view QuizView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.)

Tags: python, django

I am stuck trying to figure out how to fix this error. I know what the error is referring to (path(quizzes)), but I don't understand how to fix it although I tried pk although i may not have done it right.
Here is my url.py and models

```
urlpatterns = [
path('JSUMA/', include('JSUMA.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path("register/", v.register, name="register"),
path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
path("contact/", v.contactview, name="contact"),
path("Quizzes/", v.QuizView.as_view(), name="quiz")
```

]

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    #password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    NOQ = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    
   
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Quiz"
        verbose_name_plural = "Quizzes"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    #number Of Questions
class Major(models.Model):  
    major = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    majorData = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    answer = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.major

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey("Quiz", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __str__(self):
         return self.answer_text
```

Comment: Can you share the `QuizView`?

Comment: `class QuizView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'Quizzes/quiz.html'`

Comment: why is the `model = Question`, when the view is named `QuizView`?

Comment: I assumed it would be that because the quizview would display the question. What should it be instead

Comment: you can access the `Question`s of a `Quiz` with `myquiz.question_set.all()`.

Comment: oh ok I see now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QuizView` is a `DetailView`, thus that means we need something to specify *what* item to display. By default Django will look for a  `pk` (type `int`), or `slug` (type `slug`). You thus need to include this in the URL path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Quizzes/<int:pk>/', v.QuizView.as_view(), name='quiz')
]
```

you thus then view the item with primary key `14` for example with `/Quizzes/14/`.

then the view thus looks like:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class QuizView(DetailView):
    model = Quiz
```

in the template you can then access the related `Question`s with:

```
{% for question in object.question_set.all %}
    {{ question_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

In case you want to list *all* items, then you should use a `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class QuizView(ListView):
    # …
```

then you do not specify a `pk`/`slug`, since then the `ListView` will list all items, or perhaps a paginated variant.